# Windows Phone Certification issue :Section 5.2.3 Performance and Resource Management

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a windows phone application (silverlight) which fails certification. I do not know how to pass this certification, as I am not able to reproduce the problem as described in the failure report. 
I am displaying a `MessageBox` to the user, and the report states that the application does not resume if it is suspended keeping the MessageBox undismissed. But this doesnt happen when I am testing the app in the device, or the emulator. 
What could be the problem, and do I need to modify the application in anyway??

Comment: When you get the test report back from Microsoft aren't there steps to reproduce?

Comment: As i said, I am not able to reproduce the problem. i.e I am not getting any problem, as reported by them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem must be that the application does not resume after being 'tombstoned' not just the normal deactivation.
Go to the project options in Visual Studio and in the Debug section check the 'Tombstone upon deactivation while debugging'. Now start debugging on a device or, emulator, you should be able to see the problem regarding resume now.

Comment: I did what you told, and found that the app takes 3 seconds to resume. But it does resume, unlike reported in the cert failure report

Comment: Please tell me how to reduce the resume time.

Comment: there must be a lot of spots in your app to deactivate from... the tester must've stumbled upon one of the erroneous ones. To help you further I would need more information or the .xap as this is not a general problem.

Comment: ok. Generally, what is the process to reduce the resume time? I will first try it out, because the resume time exceeds 5 seconds sometimes which is the maximum limit for passing certification.